# Sencha Touch - looking for a good tutorial / getting started for a content application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to build a mobile "content" application that will be used to display many pages of mostly text, using Sencha Touch (based on ExtJs). I'm familiar with JQuery & JQTouch; I've never used ExtJs before.

What's the best/fastest way to get started?

I started with the "icons" demo and was able to add a scroll property ('vertical') to have content be scrollable between the top and bottom tabs (that's actually what brought me to Sencha Touch: the ability to have "fixed" toolbars).

But now what? How do I update content?

In an ExtJs tutorial ([here](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Introduction_to_Ext_2.0), near the bottom of the page) it says that one can act on an Element object to load content to an element; but that does not seem to be usable in the same way in the "icons" Sencha Touch demo.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Sencha person] I would recommend starting with the "Getting Started" guide that helps you write the GeoTweet sample application:

-- obsolete link deleted --

Update: since we released Touch 2.0 - you should start here:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/ which has links to all the getting started materials

If you're coming from jQuery/jQTouch, you'll find that Sencha does things quite a bit differently. Essentially, with Sencha Touch you're writing an object-oriented javascript application that generates HTML markup (usually bound to variables/stores) vs. with jQTouch - creating HTML markup that then gets manipulated by javascript.

I would also look at some of the better mini-apps that we've seen in the wild so far to guide you.

-- link deleted --

Update: We now have a [gallery of apps](http://www.sencha.com/apps/) for you to see what people have been up to.

Comment: > "I would also look at some of the better mini-apps that we've seen in the wild so far to guide you." Yes, but how to find them? Finding iwebapps is in itself difficult, and ones built on Sencha Touch even more difficult. (They should set up a gallery!) Cactus Festival looks interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. The Cactus Festival app is more clean and organized than the Kitchen Sink examples. (No offense, Sencha.)

Answer (score 17):

I myself am currently reading up on Sencha Touch, and found the following tutorials/articles:

- Hello World: [http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Sencha_Touch_Hello_World](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aSencha_Touch_Hello_World)
- Getting Started: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html
- MVC and PhoneGap: [http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:A_Sencha_Touch_MVC_application_with_PhoneGap](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aA_Sencha_Touch_MVC_application_with_PhoneGap)
- MVC: http://myxaab.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/sencha-touch-mvc-application-part-2/
- Data Package: http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-the-data-package-in-sencha-touch

Also, check out the examples packed within the framework and the [Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?56-Sencha-Touch-Forums).
Finally check out this [example](https://github.com/RobinQu/Phone-Demo).

update: found this one http://www.andreacammarata.com/en/corsi/sencha-touch/setup.html
Also, i read that a [Sencha Touch book "in action" will be out by the summer](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?125894-Sencha-Touch-book)...

Comment: Thanks for this; I'm not much interested in Sencha Touch anymore though (I switched to jQuery Mobile).

Answer (score 4):

This is quite good and easy to follow: [Writing a Sencha Touch Application](http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-application-part-1/)

Comment: This is Excellent !, author of the Ext book.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a sencha touch learner,I just get the toturial from sencha official website.
maybe you can hava a look this link:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/my-first-sencha-touch-experience
It is from sencha website.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus Garcia and Anthony De Moss are working on the sencha-touch book called sencha-touch in action checkout the manning publication there are some few chapters available for free to take  you through the setup and also the documentation for sench-touch-1.1.0 is detailed enough to you started

Answer (score 0):

I was in your position a few weeks ago and found this video to be the MOST helpful out of all of them out there:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5F7Gx0-W-M4&list=UU5VQSlJfHizgPCFxyx37pvg&index=6&feature=plcp

Since Sencha Touch's initial setup is a bit confusing, this guy- Rohit- really breaks it down and gets you started in no time. He even gets into pulling dynamic data from remote sources like the google maps API.

The absolute greatest tip you can take from this vid is how to use XAMPP and this terminal code (Mac) to view your project in the browser:

```
 open -a safari --args --disable-web-security
```

If the security thing makes you uneasy, I've found that the webkit browser Omniweb http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniweb/ loads projects without a problem

Answer (score 0):

Once you are off with the hello world.. you can have a look at this awesome tutorial..

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/create-a-location-aware-site-with-sencha-touch-displaying-locations/

Answer (score -1):

New hands-on tutorials for Sencha Touch, Ext JS 4, and Sencha Architect are now available at the following URL:

http://training.figleaf.com/tutorials/senchacomplete/